# How to remove duplicates in xml files using xslt?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

**Sample xml is as below:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
       <check>
        <val>
          <Samsung>
             <name value="galaxy"/>
             <name value="galaxy"/>
             <name value="galaxys"/>
             <id value="123"/>
             <id value="123"/>
             <name2 value="galaxy"/>
           </Samsung>

           <htc>
             <name value="galaxy"/>
             <name value="galaxy"/>
             <name value="galaxys"/>
             <id value="123"/>
             <id value="123"/>
             <name2 value="galaxy"/>
          </htc>
        </val>
     </check>
```

How can I remove the duplicates?

`<name>` and `<id>` tags with matching values too... Also if there are more tags other than `<Samsung>` and `<htc>`, how to write loop in xslt? I have no idea how to write xslt. Please help.

The output xml should look like:

```
<check>
    <val>
      <Samsung>
         <name value="galaxy"/>
         <name value="galaxys"/>
         <id value="123"/>
         <name2 value="galaxy"/>
       </Samsung>

       <htc>
         <name value="galaxy"/>
         <name value="galaxys"/>
         <id value="123"/>
         <name2 value="galaxy"/>
      </htc>
    </val>
 </check>
```

Comment: Firs of all your xml in not even correct. Please fix you example. And perhaps a little searching will give you are hint how to start.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure the duplicate nodes are always consecutive, then the simplest way to do this is build upon the XSTL Identity Transform an just have an extra template to strip out the templates like so

```
<xsl:template 
     match="*[not(*)]
             [name() = preceding-sibling::*[1]/name()]
             [@value = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@value]" />
```

This matches any child element, and ignores it if it has the same name and value as the previous element. There is no need to hard-code an element name anywhere in this case.

Here is the full XSLT in this case

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][name() = preceding-sibling::*[1]/name()][@value = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@value]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However this would fail if your XML looked like this, and your duplicate nodes were consecutive

```
       <Samsung>
         <name value="galaxy"/>
         <name value="galaxys"/>
         <id value="123"/>
         <name value="galaxy"/>
         <id value="123"/>
         <name2 value="galaxy"/>
       </Samsung>
```

You could fix this by changing the template to check back all previous nodes

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]
                      [name() = preceding-sibling::*/name()]
                      [@value = preceding-sibling::*/@value]" />
```

However, this starts to become inefficient with large numbers of elements. If you have hundred of elements, then each precedinig-sibling check will repeatedly involve checking hundred of elements (i.e the 100th element has to check 99 preceding ones, the 101th element checks 100 ones, etc).

A more efficient method (in XSLT1.0) is to use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). It is certainly something worth learning about if you use XSLT a lot.

First you define a key to 'group' your elements. In this case, your are looking for distinct elements defined by their parent, element name, and value

```
<xsl:key name="duplicate" match="*[not(*)]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', name(), '|', @value)" />
```

Then to ignore the duplicates, you match any element that doesn't occur in the first position in the key for the given 'lookup' value

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]
                      [generate-id() != 
                      generate-id(key('duplicate', concat(generate-id(..), '|', name(), '|', @value))[1])]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="duplicate" match="*[not(*)]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', name(), '|', @value)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][generate-id() != generate-id(key('duplicate', concat(generate-id(..), '|', name(), '|', @value))[1])]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Very god answer. I thought about something like this, but was to lazy. But wouldn't it be even better to use  `generate-id(..)` instead of `name(..)` as key? Then in would also work with more same named parent nodes.

Comment: That is a good point. I've amended my answer to do just that. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code, but it's deleting every element not just duplicates. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The original XML in your question is not actually well-formed, which suggests you are using different XML to what you have shown us. If you could show us a more accurate sample, one that is not getting the results you want, that may help. Thanks!

Comment: @ Tim C **This is sample xml on which I tried your code**`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<check>
 <val>
  <Samsung>
   <name value="galaxy" />
   <name value="galaxy" />
   <name value="galaxys" />
   <id value="123" />
   <id value="123" />
   <name2 value="galaxy" />
  </Samsung>

  <htc>
   <name value="galaxy" />
   <name value="galaxy" />
   <name value="galaxys" />
   <id value="123" />
   <id value="123" />
   <name2 value="galaxy" />
  </htc>
 </val>
</check>
`

Comment: **In this it should delete only when both node and attribute value matches like .. <name value="galaxy" /> and <id value="123" /> should be deleted as it has copies. Thanks Tim for replying**

Comment: Can you edit your question to put that XML, along with your expected results for the same XML, as it looks OK to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C.. I made changes to the question. Can you help?

Comment: I see the issue now. In your original question you wanted to check the text of an element, but now you are checking the value attribute. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28722/discussion-between-knix2-and-tim-c)

Answer (score 1):

**When this transformation**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
<xsl:if test="self::name/text()= following-sibling::name/text()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="name2">
<xsl:if test="self::name2/text()= following-sibling::name2/text()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**runs on below XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<check>
 <val>
    <sai>
     <name> A</name>
     <name> A</name>
    <name2> B</name2>
    <name2> B</name2>
   </sai>
   <dinesh>
    <name> A</name>
    <name> A</name>
    <name2> B</name2>
    <name2> B</name2>
    </dinesh>   
 </val> 
</check>
```

**gets the required output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<check> 
  <val>    
    <sai>     
      <name> A</name>       
      <name2> B</name2>
    </sai>
    <dinesh>
      <name> A</name>
      <name2> B</name2>
    </dinesh>   
   </val> 
</check>
```

Comment: Will looping the match="check/val/*/nam*" work because I have run it over other nodes too?
Where can I find the syntax definitions you wrote..Coz am finding it difficult to try without understanding the syntax.

Comment: Please try this `<?xml version='1.0'?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/><xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template><xsl:template match="check/val/*/name|name2"><xsl:if test="self::*/text()=following-sibling::*/text()"><xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:if></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: **This is the xml I tried..**

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <check>
     <val>
     <Samsung>
   <name> galaxy</name>
   <name> galaxy</name>
   <id> 123</id>
   <id> 123</id>
                        <name2> galaxy</name2>
  </Samsung>

  <htc>
   <name> ONex</name>
   <name> ONex</name>
   <id> 564</id>
   <id> 564</id>
    <name2> galaxy</name2>
  </htc>
 </val>
</check>

Comment: The output is :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<check>
 <val>
  <Samsung>
   <name> galaxy</name>
   <name> galaxy</name>
   <id> 123</id>
   
            
  </Samsung>

  <htc>
   <name> ONex</name>
   
   <id> 564</id>
   
    
  </htc>
 </val>
</check>

Comment: It's deleting <name2> tag which doesn't have duplicates and also it's not deleting <name> tag under <samsung> node which has a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly the same as in answer from @siva2012. But more correct if there is only one name child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::name[text()= $text])" >
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates  />

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```